# Get current culture in Umbraco version 7.3.5 back end with AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, umbraco

Is there an easy way to get current culture in Umbraco back end for a node? Right now I have to send `$scope.editorState.current.id` to my back end, run this C# metod `ApplicationContext.Services.ContentService.GetById(editorStateId).GetCulture().TwoLetterISOLanguageName;` and then use the value. Seems overkill if I can get the culture in front end right away.

http://umbraco.github.io/Belle/#/api/umbraco.services.editorState

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `userService` to retrieve info about the current logged in Umbraco use which includes their local:

```
userService.getCurrentUser().then(function(user) {
    console.log(user.locale);
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's "locale", not "local"?

Comment: It is, yes. Updated.

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I'm looking for exactly. I need to get the culture language of the item I'm currently on/editing. For example your code returned `en-GB` for my user but my above code returns `sv`, `sv-SE`, for a specific item.